# Why the tidyselect helper function "where" can be detected inside the dplyr helper function "across"?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyselect

The "tidyselect" package offers a select helper function `where`. `where` is used to select dataframe columns with a custom function. It is an internal function from "tidyselect". That means `where` will not be loaded to your namespace and you can only call it by `tidyselect:::where`.

However, I saw the following example from the [dplyr vignettes: columnwise operations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/colwise.html).

```
starwars %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.character), ~ length(unique(.x))))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 8
#>    name hair_color skin_color eye_color   sex gender homeworld species
#>   <int>      <int>      <int>     <int> <int>  <int>     <int>   <int>
#> 1    87         13         31        15     5      3        49      38
```

In this example, `where` is written without a prefixal "tidyselect:::" but clearly, there is no errors in the code and it produces meaningful result. This seems odd to me. I would like to know why the code functions normally.

I guess it is due to the "code quotation", which is a part of the tidyeval methodology. Roughly speaking, code quotation suspends the codes as expressions, and evaluates the expressions later in an "inner environment". This is only an intuitive guess and I don't know how to test it.

I hope someone can help me with the "where" problem, or leave some references about how the code functions for me.

Comment: The `dplyr` package imports the `tidyselect` package so the tidyselect functions are available to the `dplyr` code but are not attached to the global search path.

Comment: @MrFlick It's been a while since I made my last R package, but afaik a package import in the description file only makes sure that the package is available. If you want to use functions from it, you still need to call them by their qualified name - even from package internal code.

Comment: @AEF The user would need to qualify the function with a namespace, but if the package uses non-standard evaluation, the package can evaluate those symbols in whatever environment/namespace they like. Thus they can pass the unevaluated expression to the appropriate tidyselect  function and tidyselect will have access to all the functions in its namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not say what packages are attached in your example, but let's assume that the only attached package is `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
```

First, we notice that the function `where` is not attached, i.e. not known to the current R session. We can check by just typing its name (without parentheses) in the console. If the function was attached, we would now see its source code. Instead we get an error that object `where` was not found.

However, we note that `dplyr` attaches other functions from `tidyselect`, with `starts_with` being an example. If we repeat the experiment of typing the name to the console, we now see the source code and also that the functions originates in the `tidyselect` namespace:

```
> starts_with
function (match, ignore.case = TRUE, vars = NULL) 
{
    check_match(match)
    vars <- vars %||% peek_vars(fn = "starts_with")
    if (ignore.case) {
        vars <- tolower(vars)
        match <- tolower(match)
    }
    flat_map_int(match, starts_with_impl, vars)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000027338e5f8e8>
<environment: namespace:tidyselect>
```

In this case the function `starts_with` was attached by dplyr using the `NAMESPACE` file where you can list functions from other packages that should be attached along with your package. You can check in the `dplyr` [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/v1.0.2/NAMESPACE#L503).

But `where` is not made available this way as we have already seen. In this case the function is indeed quoted and only evaluated within the the tidyselect package. If you look at the [source code for across](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/v1.0.2/R/across.R), you'll notice that in line 82, the column specification is passes to function `across_setup` defined in the same file. In this function, the column specification is quoted (lines 174, 175) and then send to the `tidyselect` function `tidyselect::eval_select` (line 177). This function is then part of the tidyselect package and has access to `where`.

Comment: Good explanation! It would be nice to know _why_ `where` is handled differently from other select helpers (i.e. not re-exported), but likely that could only come from the developers themselves.